# What's the "if text contains" formula in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

To be specific, I want when I enter box C1 with a value like "done" both cell B and C will be colored green. For this I already did `=$C1="done"`

Tho this time I want it to change color when it contains the text "drive" since it's a box where a person will link their drive file.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this. Here are two of the most common:

`=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("drive",$C1))`

`=REGEXMATCH(LOWER($C1),"drive")`